# Как убрать заголовки значений графика chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Как убрать заголовки значений графика chart.js.
[image: заголовки графика]

```
const DATA_COUNT = 10;
const NUMBER_CFG = {count: DATA_COUNT, min: 0, max: 100};
const data = {
    labels: Utils.months({count: DATA_COUNT}),
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        borderColor: Utils.randomColor(0.7),
        backgroundColor: Utils.randomColor(0.5),
        data: Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG),
    }, {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        borderColor: Utils.randomColor(0.7),
        backgroundColor: Utils.randomColor(0.5),
        data: Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG),
    }, {
        label: 'Dataset 3',
        borderColor: Utils.randomColor(0.7),
        backgroundColor: Utils.randomColor(0.5),
        data: Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG),
    }]
};
const scaleOpts = {
    grid: {
        borderColor: Utils.randomColor(1),
        color: 'rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
    },
    title: {
        display: false,
        text: (ctx) => ctx.scale.axis + ' axis',
    }
};
const scales = {
    x: {
        type: 'category',
        min: 5,
        max: 11,
    },
    y: {
        type: 'linear',
        max: 100,
        ticks: {
            callback: function(value){return value+ "%"}
        },
    },
};
Object.keys(scales).forEach(scale => Object.assign(scales[scale], scaleOpts));
const zoomOptions = {
    pan: {
        enabled: true,
        mode: 'x',
        threshold: 5,
    },
    zoom: {
        wheel: {
            enabled: true,
        },
        pinch: {
            enabled: true
        },
        mode: 'x',
    }
}
new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-grouped"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['август','сентябрь','октябрь','ноябрь','декабрь','январь','февраль','март','апрель','май','июнь','июль','август','сентябрь'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Продажи наличные',
                backgroundColor: "#F88587",
                data: [51,36,74,37,73,37,75,37,37,27,75,27,71,47],
                barPercentage: .8,
                categoryPercentage: .3,
            }, {
                label: 'Продажи безнал',
                backgroundColor: "#5BADAB",
                data: [71,31,77,26,83,93,27,83,94,26,38,72,45,84],
                barPercentage: .8,
                categoryPercentage: .3,

            },
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Population growth (millions)'
        },
        scales: scales,
        plugins: {
            zoom: zoomOptions
        },
        animations: {
            tension: {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: 'easeInBack',
                from: 1,
                to: 0,
                loop: true
            }
        },
        animation: true
    },
});
const actions = [
    {
        name: 'Reset zoom',
        handler(chart) {
            chart.resetZoom();
        }
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот это

```
var chart1 = new Chart(canvas, {
    type: "pie",
    data: data,
    options: {
         legend: {
            display: false
         },
         tooltips: {
            enabled: false
         }
    }
});
```

Вы можете изменить параметры по умолчанию, используя Chart.defaults.global в вашем файле javascript. Итак, вы хотите изменить параметры легенды и всплывающей подсказки.
Удалить легенду
`Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;`
Удалить всплывающую подсказку
`Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.enabled = false;`

Comment: Прикрепил код, вставил ваши строчки, не работает.
Может есть другие способы?

Comment: Надо поместить это в плагин, вот так:plugins: {legend: {display: false}}